# How to remove the OSX-GCC-Installer?

Tags: xcode, gcc, osx-lion, llvm-gcc

Just a couple of days ago I discovered and used Kenneth Reitz's **[OSX-GCC-Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)** to solve the issue of [installing Ruby 1.9.3 via RVM](http://www.unfoldingcode.com/2012/02/ruby-193-via-rvm-on-mac-osx-lion.html) on my Mac.

Today I read on Kenneth's blog about the **[Command Line Tools for Xcode](http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html)** package that Apple added to their official developer tools suite just yesterday for Lion users.

I try to keep the number of installed packages to a minimum, so given this alternative, what's the *safe* way to remove what was added by the OSX-GCC-Installer?

Comment: Have you tried running the uninstall script in `/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` and then installing the official package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [creator of the package](http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html#comment-442259045), you can install Xcode on top of it since it is just a subset. Then you can use the uninstall command to completely remove:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Definitely not a quick uninstall, but it should work.

Comment: So this will uninstall both xcode and the command line tools?
After this we need to install xcode again along with the command line tools?

Comment: it was `sudo /Library/Developer/4.1/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` on my system 10.8.4

Answer (score 5):

Just an update for anyone coming across this now.

If you download Xcode 4.3 or later (**in order to install over OSX-GCC to facilitate removal**) it is bundled as a single app, so to uninstall, delete the Xcode app rather than using the command mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

From https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/uninstalling-osxgccinstaller:

```
sudo /Library/Developer/4.1/uninstall-devtools -mode=all
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work with Xcode 5.x. You'd need to follow the answer **snacks** has given, or you could also remove the `/Developer` directory with this simple command:

```
sudo rm -rf /Developer
```

Problem gone. The only issue I have with the original OSX-gcc uninstaller, is they never created a proper uninstaller to begin with. I was using Pacifist to have a look at the bundled components with the installer, and was trying to figure a way to remove it completely. I might pick this back up sometime again soon and finish it off.

Comment: Since XCode 4.3 there is no longer a /Developer folder.